# mysql check if post is liked or not

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables (likes),(posts) and (users), and in my program I get the posts by user id,while doing this I want to return if i liked posts or not, I tried to do it like this

```
$query="SELECT post , users.name, users.profile_pic , users.uid , posts.likes , posts.comments , posts.createdAt , posts.pid, 
            IF('$uid' IN (SELECT uid FROM likes WHERE uid='$uid' AND pid=this.posts.pid), 1, 0) AS i_liked
            FROM posts
            INNER JOIN users
            ON users.uid = posts.uid
            WHERE posts.uid = '$uid' OR posts.uid 
            IN (SELECT users.uid
                FROM friends
                INNER JOIN users
                ON users.uid=friends.ruid OR users.uid=friends.luid
                WHERE accept=1 AND (friends.luid='$uid' OR friends.ruid='$uid') AND users.uid!='$uid')

            ORDER BY posts.createdAt DESC
            LIMIT $loaded_posts, 20";
```

but it shows that there is an error at "pid=this.posts.pid"

Comment: What is `this` supposed to mean in that context …?

Comment: i want to point to the currently proccessed row

Comment: There is no `this` in a query. Take `this.` out and it should fix that problem.

Comment: _“i want to point to the currently proccessed row”_ – and what made you think it would work that way …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `this.posts.pid` with `posts.pid`.